# Unique constraint to specific text

Tags: sql, postgresql, unique

I have the following table

```
create table order(
status text,
user_id int (FK to user table),
time time stamp with time zone

);
```

And the following constraint for status

```
CONSTRAINT valid_status CHECK (status = ANY (ARRAY['requested'::text, 'accepted'::text, 'declined_by_manager'::text, 'declined_by_user'::text, 'finished_by_user'::text, 'canceled_by_system'::text, 'washing'::text, 'finished_by_manager'::text]))
```

What i want is , there is can be only one order with status 'requested'and with user "n"
Smth like `Alter table order add constraint "only_one_order_per_user" UNIQUE(user_id, status = 'requested')`
I'm really newbee with Postgres. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
create unique index some_name on "order" (user_id, (case when status = 'requested' then 1 else null end));
```

with idea behind that null <> null

also maybe you better use `ENUM` for status?.. Or even better create a relation statuses with distinct rows and FK?..

sample:

```
t=# create table "order" (
status text,
user_id int,
time timestamp with time zone
);
CREATE TABLE
Time: 6.345 ms
t=# create unique index some_name on "order" (user_id, (case when status = 'requested' then 1 else null end));
CREATE INDEX
Time: 16.979 ms
t=# insert into "order" select 'requested',1,now();
INSERT 0 1
Time: 17.793 ms
t=# insert into "order" select 'other',1,now();
INSERT 0 1
Time: 1.137 ms
t=# insert into "order" select 'other',1,now();
INSERT 0 1
Time: 6.735 ms
t=# insert into "order" select 'other',1,now();
INSERT 0 1
Time: 0.867 ms
t=# insert into "order" select 'requested',1,now();
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "some_name"
DETAIL:  Key (user_id, (
CASE
    WHEN status = 'requested'::text THEN 1
    ELSE NULL::integer
END))=(1, 1) already exists.
Time: 0.342 ms
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You should be able to build your table so you can only have requested status, not sure if NULL is allowed however. Then add a unique for user_id and status.

```
create table order(
status text CHECK (status in ('requested'[add more statuses here])) ,
user_id int,
time time stamp with time zone
UNIQUE (status, user_id) 
);
```

Comment: Thank for response, but status is not only requested, it can be finished, accepted and on, CONSTRAINT valid_status CHECK (status = ANY (ARRAY['requested'::text, 'accepted'::text, 'declined_by_manager'::text, 'declined_by_user'::text, 'finished_by_user'::text, 'canceled_by_system'::text, 'washing'::text, 'finished_by_manager'::text]))

Comment: In your case i will not be able to create 2 declined_by_user orders.I need only one order with status "requested" and ith user_id like 1